# MVC 4 Html.Editor ignores EditorTemplate

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-editor-templates

I'm trying to implement some custom EditorTemplates but they're only being rendered by my Create view, and not the Edit one.

**Model**

```
public class Page {
    public int PageID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Html)]
    [AllowHtml]
    // I tried including [UIHint("Html")] but this made no difference
    public string Content { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Html.cshtml**

```
@model string
@Html.TextArea("", Model, new { @class = "html"})
```

**/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Object.cshtml**

```
@if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1)
{
    @ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText

} else {

    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

    foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForEdit
                         && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm)))
    {
        if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml) {
            @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)
            @prop.DataTypeName
        } else {
            <div class="form-field">
                @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Html.Label(prop.PropertyName).ToHtmlString())) {
                    @Html.Label(prop.PropertyName)
                }
                @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

**/Views/Page/Create.cshtml** ( This correctly renders `Html.cshtml` )

```
@model MvcDisplayTemplates.Models.Page

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.EditorForModel(Model)
    <p><input type="submit" value="Create" /></p>
}
```

**/Views/Page/Edit.cshtml** ( This simply renders the default single line text editor )

```
@model MvcDisplayTemplates.Models.Page

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.EditorForModel(Model)
    <p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>
}
```

Interestingly, if I use `EditorFor` on `Edit.cshtml` then `Html.cshtml` is actually rendered. e.g.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content)
```

**UPDATE:** If I delete `object.cshtml` then `Html.cshtml` is also rendered correctly. So this does seem to be an issue in `Object.cshtml`. It just seems odd that it works on one view but not another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed by explicitly setting the template in `Object.cshtml`

```
@Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName, prop.TemplateHint ?? prop.DataTypeName)
```

Still not clear why it previously worked in one view but not the other though.